# Change order of y-axis labels on a odds ratio plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the following visualisation of odds ratio

[odds ratio plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U47YD.png)

This is the code I am using

```
boxLabels = c("Past encounter", "Mutualism WVO:\nNon-hunting wildlife experiences", "Domination WVO:\nEthics of hunting", "Domination WVO:\nWildlife management", "Age", "Education", "Negative attitudes toward box turtles", "Gender")

df <- data.frame(yAxis = length(boxLabels):1,
  boxOdds = 
   c(2.23189,1.315737,1.22866,.8197413,.9802449,.9786673,.6559005,.5929812),
  boxCILow = 
   c(.7543566,1.016,.9674772,.6463458,.9643047,.864922,.4965308,.3572142),
  boxCIHigh = 
  c(6.603418,1.703902,1.560353,1.039654,.9964486,1.107371,.8664225,.9843584)
)


(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = boxLabels)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = 
      .2, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_point(size = 3.5, color = 'orange') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
  ylab('') +
  xlab('Odds ratio (log scale)') +
  annotate(geom = 'text', y =1.1, x = 3.5, label ='Model p < 0.001\nPseudo 
R^2 = 0.10', size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + ggtitle('Intention to remove box 
turtles from the road')
)
```

How can I change the order of the y-axis labels e.g. Domination WVO:\nWildlife management, age, Mutualism WVO:\nNon-hunting wildlife experiences, past encounter, from the top down

Also, how do I change the colour of one point to blue, and keep the rest orange?

Comment: Does the x data match the y labels correctly? Or do you just want the labels to move? Do you want descending order?

Comment: For highlighting , just add another geom_point() to the end of your plot with the index of the point you want to highlight. If you want to highlight the first point then:                              `+ geom_point(data=df,  aes(x=boxOdds[1],y=boxLabels[1]), color='blue', size=3)`

Comment: @SEAnalyst The x data matches the y labels - I want in a specific order, so the order it is listed in box labels on the first line

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the automatic alphabetical order of the y labels, convert to `factor()` with the order you want. Then use `scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)` to get the order in the correct orientation. Complete example:

```
boxLabels = c("Past encounter", "Mutualism WVO:\nNon-hunting wildlife experiences", "Domination WVO:\nEthics of hunting", "Domination WVO:\nWildlife management", "Age", "Education", "Negative attitudes toward box turtles", "Gender")

#Add a "ylabel" to dataframe
df <- data.frame(yAxis = length(boxLabels):1,
                 ylabel = boxLabels,
                 boxOdds = 
                   c(2.23189,1.315737,1.22866,.8197413,.9802449,.9786673,.6559005,.5929812),
                 boxCILow = 
                   c(.7543566,1.016,.9674772,.6463458,.9643047,.864922,.4965308,.3572142),
                 boxCIHigh = 
                   c(6.603418,1.703902,1.560353,1.039654,.9964486,1.107371,.8664225,.9843584)
)
#Convert the 'ylabel' into a factor with levels set by oder of boxlabels
df$ylabel<-factor(df$ylabel, levels = boxLabels)

#"boxlabel" is now the y. Intially give you the reverse order
(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = ylabel)) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = 'dashed') +
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = 
                     .2, color = 'gray50') +
    geom_point(size = 3.5, color = 'orange') +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
    coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
    ylab('') +
    xlab('Odds ratio (log scale)') +
    annotate(geom = 'text', y =1.1, x = 3.5, label ='Model p < 0.001\nPseudo 
R^2 = 0.10', size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + ggtitle('Intention to remove box 
turtles from the road')+
    #highlight one point as blue, as requested
    geom_point(data=df, 
               aes(x=boxOdds[1],y=ylabel[1]), 
               color='blue',
               size=3.5)
)
#Get correct order with scale_y_discrete()
p+scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)
```